# Sign in form validation in PHP

Tags: php

I am validating a sign in page form in PHP I have this code:

```
if($customerCount > 0) {
   if(password_verify($password_2, $customer['password'])) {
      if($customer['isEmailConfirmed'] == 0) {
          $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please verify your email!</span>";
      } else {
          $customer_id = $customer['id'];
          login_2($customer_id);
      }
   } else {
       $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>The email address and password combination you provided was not found. Please try again.</span>";
   }
} else {
      $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>The email address is not registered in our system.</span>";
}
```

And it works fine. But I need to add

```
if(empty($_POST['email_3']) || empty($_POST['password_3'])){
    $msg_2 = 'You must provide email and password.';
}
```

If both email and password and left blank. Also I need to display message if email is filled but password blank and vice versa. Now how could I add these codes to my validation. I'm getting confused and lost about all these if statements. Where should I add these and how ??

Comment: What would happen if you just **add** this code? If you don't understand your code, it's time to refactor it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

// changed || to &&
if(empty($_POST['email_3']) && empty($_POST['password_3'])) {
    $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>You must provide email and password.</span>";
}
// No need to write this code.
else if(empty($_POST['email_3']) && !empty($_POST['password_3'])) {
    $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter a valid email address.</span>";
}
/*
    You can write this code for validate email
else if(!empty($_POST['email_3']) && filter_var($_POST['email_3'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter a valid email address.</span>";
}
*/
else {
    // Please write your remaining code

    if($customerCount > 0) {
        if(password_verify($password_2, $customer['password'])) {
            if($customer['isEmailConfirmed'] == 0) {
                $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please verify your email!</span>";
            } else {
                $customer_id = $customer['id'];
                login_2($customer_id);
            }
        } else {
            $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>The email address and password combination you provided was not found. Please try again.</span>";
        }
    } else {
        $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>The email address is not registered in our system.</span>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes, this code works fine but when I added `if(empty($_POST['email_3']) && !empty($_POST['passwordl_3'])) {
            $msg_2 = "Please enter a valid email address.";
        }` where you say `// write remaining code if fields are not empty` it does not work ...

Comment: "// write remaining code if fields are not empty"

those are comments for your help.

Comment: Oh, ok sorry. Where should I add if(empty($_POST['email_3']) && !empty($_POST['passwordl_3'])) { $msg_2 = "Please enter a valid email address."; } ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sequential algoritm. In this way it is easy to add a lot of validation, keeping the readability ok.

```
$everythingOk = true;
$errMessage = '';
if (empty($_POST['email_3']) {
  $everythingOk = false;
  $errMessage = 'Email 3 empty';
}
if ($everythingOk && empty($_POST['password_3']) {
  $everythingOk = false;
  $errMessage = 'Password 3 empty';
}
if ($everythingOk && ($customerCount === 0)) {
  $everythingOk = false;
  $errMessage = 'Customer count error';
}
........
if ($everythingOk) {
  // all info ok, move on
} else {
  // info is not valid
  // message is in $errMessage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to place it all into a function and return a result. The way you are doing your if statements you end up with a big V and makes it very hard to read at times:

```
<?php

$loginCheck = getLogin( $_POST , $customer , $password_2 );
if( is_array( $loginCheck ) ){ // if error messages are present
    // Login errors
    foreach( $loginCheck  as $errorMsg ){
        echo $errorMsg . '<br />';
    }
} 
if( $loginCheck ){ //assuming login_2 returns boolean true if logged in
  echo 'Logged In!';
}


function getLogin( $details , $customer , $password ){

    $errors[]; //set errors array to catch all errors
    if(empty($details['email_3'])){
        $errors[] = "You must provide an email.";
    }

    if(empty($details['password_3'])){
        $errors[] = "You must provide a password.";
    }

    if( ! empty( $errors[] ) ){
        //fatal error no point going futher
        return $errors;
    }
    if( ! $customer ) { //assuming if no email is found $customer returns boolean
        $errors[] = "<span class='text-danger'>The email address is not registered in our system.</span>";
    }

    if( ! password_verify( $password , $customer['password'] ) ) {
        $errors[] = "<span class='text-danger'>The email address and password combination you provided was not found. Please try again.</span>"
    }

    if($customer['isEmailConfirmed'] === 0) {
        $errors[] = "<span class='text-danger'>Please verify your email!</span>";
    }

    return login_2($customer['id']);
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    if(empty($_POST['email_3'])) {
        // Email is left blank
        if(empty($_POST['password_3'])) {
            // Password is also blank
            $msg_2 = "You must provide email and password.";
        } else {
            // Only email is blank
            $msg_2 = "You must provide email address.";
        }
    } elseif(empty($_POST['password_3']) && !empty($_POST['email_3'])) {
            // Only password is blank
            $msg_2 = "You must provide a password.";
        }
    }
    // Your custom form validation goes here
?>
```

The first `if` checks whether the email is blank or not. The nested `if` checks meanwhile if the password is also blank. If this is the case, the message `You must provide email and password.` is assigned to `$msg_2`; otherwise this is `You must provide email address.`.

The `elseif` checks if the password is empty *AND* if the email is not empty. If this is the case, the third message is put into `$msg_2`.